# Extract Hashtags in Rails using Twitter-Text-Rb Gem

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter, hashtag

I am a Rails Newbie. I am trying to implement Hashtags in my project.

I have been looking at the following posts this and twitter gem.

This is my Tweets Controller:

```
def index
    @tweets = Tweet.all
end
```

My Tweet Model

```
class Tweet < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Twitter::Extractor
    def extract_tags
        extract_hashtags(self.post)
    end
end
```

This is my View:

```
<% @tweets.each do |tweet| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= tweet.post %></td>
    <td><%= tweet.extract_tags %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

In my browser.. this is what I see

```
#Rails is #awesome  ["Rails", "awesome"]    Show    Edit    Destroy
#37 Signals         []  Show    Edit    Destroy
Ruby on #rails  ["rails"]   Show    Edit    Destroy
```

How do I combine all these individual array of hashtags into one big array?

How do I also display the most popular ones over a period of time.. lets say popular for the past 15 minutes, 1 hr etc.

Looking for help. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all tags from all tweets in one array like this:

```
@tweets.map(&:extract_tags).inject(:+)
# or
@tweets.map(&:extract_tags).flatten
```

If you don't want repeated tags, add `uniq` in the end.

```
@tweets.map(&:extract_tags).flatten.uniq
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! How can I display them as a list? Also, how to save them to the database?

Comment: @reko: you could, for example, build an unordered list (`<ul>`) out of them. Saving is also pretty simple. But both these questions are out of scope :-)